# Laravel 5 - Unable to call User class

Tags: model, eloquent, laravel-5

I am trying to pull all users from my DB in my controller and then pass it to the view with the follow function.

```
public function carriers(){
    $aAllUsers = User::all();
    return view('carriers')->with("aAllUsers", $aAllUsers);
}
```

I am getting the following error

FatalErrorException in CarriersController.php line 24:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\User' not found
in CarriersController.php line 24
at HandleExceptions->fatalExceptionFromError(array('type' => '1', 'message' => 'Class 'App\Http\Controllers\User' not found', 'file' => '/Users/andrewmccallum/Documents/webdev/mobileMe/app/Http/Controllers/CarriersController.php', 'line' => '24')) in HandleExceptions.php line 116
at HandleExceptions->handleShutdown()

As you already know, the user model comes included already in laravel 5 so unsure why it can't find a pre-existing class. Could it be my DB config?

Sorry if I haven't included enough information, I am not sure what else would be helpful so let me know if you would like me to post more code.

Comment: Sounds like you need to include 'use App\User;' at the top of your controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, you need to include User class by using use statement in Laravel 5.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

// write this to include User class
use App\User;

class CarriersController extends Copntroller
{
    public function carriers()
    {
        $aAllUsers = User::all();
        return view('carriers')->with("aAllUsers", $aAllUsers);
    }
}
```